# Problem with joint use of multicols and eqnarray

Tags: equations, multicolumn, multicol, eqnarray

I am using multicols and eqnarray, as shown below. However, I don´t know how to get rid of the vertical space before equation (1) and also how to align the lines across columns. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage {multicol}
\begin {document}
nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono 
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{eqnarray}
S & \rightarrow & aX \label {eqn03:01:03:01} \\
S & \rightarrow & bX \label {eqn03:01:03:02} \\
S & \rightarrow & cX \label {eqn03:01:03:03} \\
X & \rightarrow & aY \label {eqn03:01:03:04} \\
X & \rightarrow & bY \label {eqn03:01:03:05} \\
X & \rightarrow & cY \label {eqn03:01:03:06} \\
Y & \rightarrow & a  \label {eqn03:01:03:07} \\
Y & \rightarrow & b  \label {eqn03:01:03:08} \\
Y & \rightarrow & c  \label {eqn03:01:03:09}
\end {eqnarray}
\end {multicols}
nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono 
\end {document}
```

[image]

Comment: unrelated but `eqnarray` is rather deprecated, it is almost always better to use `align` from `amsmath`  also beware using equation numbers in `\label` it's not an error but it can be very confusing when readng the source.

Comment: To me, the important thing here is that automatic breaking of the list is wanted.  Items can be added to the list, anywhere, and breaking still occurs in a reasonable place.  (I haven't tried `\allowdisplaybreaks` with `align`, so don't know whether or not it works.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No math display really works without a paragraph of text before it, the two column view makes the spurious line more obvious, you can prevent the empty paragraph with `\noindent`

[image]

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage {multicol}
\begin {document}
nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono 
\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent
\begin{eqnarray}
S & \rightarrow & aX \label {eqn03:01:03:01} \\
S & \rightarrow & bX \label {eqn03:01:03:02} \\
S & \rightarrow & cX \label {eqn03:01:03:03} \\
X & \rightarrow & aY \label {eqn03:01:03:04} \\
X & \rightarrow & bY \label {eqn03:01:03:05} \\
X & \rightarrow & cY \label {eqn03:01:03:06} \\
Y & \rightarrow & a  \label {eqn03:01:03:07} \\
Y & \rightarrow & b  \label {eqn03:01:03:08} \\
Y & \rightarrow & c  \label {eqn03:01:03:09}
\end {eqnarray}
\end {multicols}
nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono 
\end {document}
```

Comment: Worked, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you should use  `eqnarray`– the spacing around alignment points is not good. I propose to use two minipages and the `align`  environment:

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage {multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin {document}

nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono\vskip -3ex

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{align}
S & \rightarrow aX \label {eqn03:01:03:01} \\
S & \rightarrow bX \label {eqn03:01:03:02} \\
S & \rightarrow cX \label {eqn03:01:03:03} \\
X & \rightarrow aY \label {eqn03:01:03:04} \\
X & \rightarrow bY \label {eqn03:01:03:05}
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{align}
X & \rightarrow cY \label {eqn03:01:03:06} \\
Y & \rightarrow a \label {eqn03:01:03:07} \\
Y & \rightarrow b \label {eqn03:01:03:08} \\
Y & \rightarrow c \label {eqn03:01:03:09}
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\vskip 3ex

nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono

\end {document}
```

[image]

Comment: But the column break must be specified manually.  Not ideal if items are to be added to the list.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `eqnarray`. The following computes the number of items and populates two sequences, for the items on the left and the ones on the right, then it makes two minipages with distinct `align` environments.

Note that you don't get an indentation after the display, if you don't leave a blank line, which is what normally happens, but wouldn't with `multicols`.

Don't use `$$`, unless you know what you're doing (I know, here).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usepackage{xparse} % uncomment if using LaTeX prior to 2020-10-01

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{twocolalign}{b}
 {
  \marcus_twocolalign:n { #1 }
 }
 {\ignorespacesafterend}

\seq_new:N \l_marcus_twocolalign_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l_marcus_twocolalign_left_seq
\seq_new:N \l_marcus_twocolalign_right_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \marcus_twocolalign:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_marcus_twocolalign_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l_marcus_twocolalign_seq
   {
    \int_compare:nTF
     {
      ##1 % the current item index
      <=  % is less than or equal to half the number of items
      \int_div_truncate:nn { \seq_count:N \l_marcus_twocolalign_seq + 1 } { 2 }
     }
     {% put in the left column
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l_marcus_twocolalign_left_seq { ##2 }
     }
     {% put in the right column
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l_marcus_twocolalign_right_seq { ##2 }
     }
   }
  $$
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\displaywidth}
  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
  \begin{align}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_marcus_twocolalign_left_seq { \\ }
  \end{align}
  \end{minipage}
  \hspace{0.1\displaywidth}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\displaywidth}
  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
  \begin{align}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_marcus_twocolalign_right_seq { \\ }
  \end{align}
  \end{minipage}
  $$
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono 
nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono 
\begin{twocolalign}
S & \rightarrow aX \label {eqn03:01:03:01} \\
S & \rightarrow bX \label {eqn03:01:03:02} \\
S & \rightarrow cX \label {eqn03:01:03:03} \\
X & \rightarrow aY \label {eqn03:01:03:04} \\
X & \rightarrow bY \label {eqn03:01:03:05} \\
X & \rightarrow cY \label {eqn03:01:03:06} \\
Y & \rightarrow a  \label {eqn03:01:03:07} \\
Y & \rightarrow b  \label {eqn03:01:03:08} \\
Y & \rightarrow c  \label {eqn03:01:03:09}
\end{twocolalign}
nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono 
nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono 

\end{document}
```

[image]